# ES6 spread to merge objects in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to merge objects in an array with ES6 spread operator? Let's say we have objects like this:

```
    let arr = [{ a: 1, b: true }, { c: "val", d: null }];
```

and this object as an result:

```
    { a: 1, b: true, c: "val", d: null };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could spread the elements into an [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), without further looping.

```js
let arr = [{ a: 1, b: true }, { c: "val", d: null }],
    result = Object.assign({}, ...arr);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `Array.prototype.reduce()` function ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)).

```js
let arr = [{ a: 1, b: true }, { c: "val", d: null }];
let obj = arr.reduce((accumulator, current) => ({...accumulator, ...current}), {});
console.log(obj);
```

As always, with returning object literals from arrow function, don't forget to wrap return value with paremtheses `(...)` like this `({...accumulator, ...current})` in order to distinguish between code block and object literal ([docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)).

Comment: Needlessly verbose. Instead, use `Object.assign({}, ...arr)`